# How to setup FileZilla to not overwrite files being moved on remote server?

Tags: ftp, filezilla

Is it possible to set FileZilla to not overwrite files that I'm moving from one folder to another on my remote server? Can FileZilla show a prompt asking if to overwrite, or simply prevent overwrites?

I'm connecting to my server using plain FTP.

If it's not possible with FileZilla, are there there other FTP programs that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a common behavior of an FTP server, when renaming a file to a name of an already existing file, is to fail the rename.

- FileZilla FTP server:

  ```
  Command:  RNFR file.txt
  Response: 350 File exists, ready for destination name.
  Command:  RNTO /dest/file.txt
  Response: 553 file exists
  ```
- Microsoft IIS FTP server:

  ```
  Command:  RNFR file.txt
  Response: 350 Requested file action pending further information.
  Command:  RNTO /dest/file.txt
  Response: 550-Cannot create a file when that file already exists. 
  Response:  Win32 error:   Cannot create a file when that file already exists. 
  Response:  Error details: File system returned an error.
  Response: 550 End
  ```

---

I believe that FileZilla (rightfully) expects this behavior and does not even even check if the target file exists, let alone prompt you for confirmation.